# How to pass an argument to calculator?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to speed up my calculator. How would i got about that?

Comment: If you're trying just to print a nth Fibonacci number, just define `fibs` as `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` and use `(!!)` when you need it. Be careful though, this has `O(n)` complexity if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `fib n = fib !! n does not work` - this is the right approach though, the only reason it doesn't work is that you can't use the name `fib` for both the infinite list of Fibonacce numbers and the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `fib` as the name of the function that gets the nth Fibonacci number and the name of the generating list.

This should work:

`fibList = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibList (tail fibList)`

`fib n = fibList !! n`